# Facebook "Unable to update association between Page and App"

Tags: ios, facebook

I am an iOS developer that recently integrated the Facebook SDK into my company's mobile app. We already had an existing business page, and as an admin of that page I tried to "Create an App" - to which facebook told me I needed to do so from a personal account. After logging in to a personal account I created the iOS app following the directions, and everything thus far works 100% for the exception of one thing - linking facebook shares from the iOS app to our business facebook page via the web (not the app). In other words, when sharing information from our app, inside of the share dialog on facebook when users click on  in "John Doe shared a link via ", I want users to be directed to our facebook page. I currently have it working so that if the user is on facebook using the mobile app and they click on the share it takes them to the app store if they dont have the app or opens the app if they have it, but if they are on their computer and click on the company name I want to direct them to our facebook page.

After becoming an admin for the business facebook page on my personal account, I was able to go to "Manage Apps", "Edit App", and then "App Details", where there is a section to "select an existing facebook page" that I am an admin for. The dropdown includes the business' facebook page, and after selecting it and then hitting save I am given the following message:

"Error. We were unable to update the association between your Facebook Page and your app. Try again later."

This has been going on for a few days now. Does anyone know what the issue is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was a known issue with Facebook, and has since been fixed by them.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1483912231834857

Answer (score 0):

This error seems to crop up for a multitude of reasons, so you'll need to check a few things :

- Under the "Settings" for your application, make sure Sandbox Mode is still **disabled**.
- Verify that your App Id and App Secret have not changed.
- Make sure the page is categorized as an App Page (and can be found under Brands & Products)
- Make sure the Page name contains your app name.

Comment: The page name is identical to the app name, sandbox mode is disabled, the app id is the same, its categorized as an app page and under brands and products, the only thing there I'm not sure about is the app secret - I don't recall doing anything with it, and nowhere in the facebook docs did I find mention of the secret when setting up the app and allowing sharing.